# Will Ubunut 14.04 LTS update OpenSSL to 1.0.2 after EOL of 1.0.1

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, openssl

According to OpenSSL, the version 1.0.1 has reached EOL: https://www.openssl.org/policies/releasestrat.html

Which means:

> Support for version 1.0.1 will cease on 2016-12-31. No further
>   releases of 1.0.1 will be made after that date. Security fixes only
>   will be applied to 1.0.1 until then.

Unfortunatelly Ubunut 14.04 LTS still has not upgraded to 1.0.2:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/openssl

How is this handeled in the future? I need a feature of 1.0.2 and hope for Canonnical upgrading to this version due to EOL. What would you recommend? Waiting for an official upgrade or compiling from source to a different directory?